# Android Expandable Listivew gets Uncaught Remote Exception

Tags: java, android, listview

I am creating an android application in which having one listview, inside that listview having expandable listview. When I run the application I'm getting the uncaught remote exception in logcat. Can any one tell me why this error occurs, what I have done wrong in following code?

ListAdapter:

```
public class Daybook_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
private ArrayList<Daybook> entriesdaybook;
private ArrayList<Daybooklist> daybooklists = new ArrayList<Daybooklist>();
private boolean isListScrolling;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public Daybook_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Daybook> entriesdaybook) {
    this.context = context;
    this.entriesdaybook = entriesdaybook;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return entriesdaybook.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return entriesdaybook.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.model_daybook, null);

    final TextView tv_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_date);
    final TextView tv_cashin = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_cashin);
    final TextView tv_cashout = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_cashout);
    final TextView tv_totalamt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.daybook_total_amt);
    final ImageView img_pdf = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_printpdf);
    LinearLayout emptyy = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.empty);
    ExpandableHeightListView daybookdetailviewlist = (ExpandableHeightListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detaillist_daybook);


    final Daybook m = entriesdaybook.get(position);
    String s = m.getDate();
    String[] spiliter = s.split("-");
    String year = spiliter[0];
    String month = spiliter[1];
    String date = spiliter[2];
    if (month.startsWith("01")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Jan" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("02")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Feb" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("03")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Mar" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("04")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Apr" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("05")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "May" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("06")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Jun" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("07")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Jul" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("08")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Aug" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("09")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Sep" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("10")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Oct" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("11")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Nov" + year);
    } else if (month.startsWith("12")) {
        tv_date.setText(date + "Dec" + year);
    }
    tv_cashin.setText("\u20B9" + m.getCashin());
    tv_cashout.setText("\u20B9" + m.getCashout());
    double one = Double.parseDouble(m.getCashin());
    double two = Double.parseDouble(m.getCashout());
    double three = one + two;
    tv_totalamt.setText("\u20B9" + String.valueOf(three));
    DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    daybooklists = databaseHandler.getAllDaywisedaybookdetails(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < daybooklists.size(); i++) {
        try {
            Daybooklist_adapter adapter = new Daybooklist_adapter(context, daybooklists);
            if (adapter != null) {
                if (adapter.getCount() > 0) {
                    emptyy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    daybookdetailviewlist.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            } else {
                daybookdetailviewlist.setEmptyView(emptyy);
            }
            daybookdetailviewlist.setExpanded(true);
            daybookdetailviewlist.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
            if (!isListScrolling) {
                img_pdf.setEnabled(false);
                adapter.isScrolling(true);
            } else {
                img_pdf.setEnabled(true);
                adapter.isScrolling(false);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    img_pdf.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Click yes to Print Report for : " + m.getDate())
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, close
                            // current activity
                            Intent pdfreport = new Intent(context, Activity_Daybookpdf.class);
                            pdfreport.putExtra("date", m.getDate());
                            context.startActivity(pdfreport);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
            Button nbutton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            nbutton.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            Button pbutton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            pbutton.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            pbutton.setPadding(0, 10, 10, 0);
            pbutton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            return false;

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public void setTransactionList(ArrayList<Daybook> newList) {
    entriesdaybook = newList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void isScrolling(boolean isScroll) {
    isListScrolling = isScroll;
    Log.e("scrollcheck", String.valueOf(isListScrolling));
}
}
```

Expandable ListAdapter:

```
public class Daybooklist_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Daybooklist> daybooklists;
DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
boolean isListScrolling;

public Daybooklist_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Daybooklist> daybooklists) {
    this.context = context;
    this.daybooklists = daybooklists;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return daybooklists.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return daybooklists.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertview == null)
        convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.model_daybook_listentry, null);
    final TextView day_name = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_name);
    final TextView day_description = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_description);
    final TextView day_type = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_type);
    final TextView day_amount = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_amount);
    final TextView day_usertype = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_usertype);
    final TextView day_time = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_time);
    final ImageView day_check = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.img_doneall);
    final TextView daybook_location = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_location);
    databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    final Daybooklist m = daybooklists.get(position);
    if (m.getUsertype() != null && !m.getUsertype().isEmpty()) {
        if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("singleworker") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("groupworker") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("payvehicle")) {
            if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer")) {
                day_name.setText(m.getName());
                day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
                String locat = String.valueOf(databaseHandler.getfarmerlocation(m.getMobileno()));
                locat = locat.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
                Log.e("farmerlocation", locat);
                daybook_location.setText(locat);
                day_type.setText(m.getType());
                if (m.getName() != null && m.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (m.getDescription() != null && m.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }

                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getExtraamt());
                if (m.getAmountout().startsWith("0.0") | m.getAmountout().startsWith("0")) {
                    //     day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    Log.e("Amountout", m.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    //    day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.album_title));
                    Log.e("Amountout", m.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            } else {
                day_name.setText(m.getName());
                day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
                daybook_location.setText(m.getType());
                day_type.setText(m.getType());
                if (m.getName() != null && m.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (m.getDescription() != null && m.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }

                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getExtraamt());
                if (m.getAmountout().startsWith("0.0") | m.getAmountout().startsWith("0")) {
                    //  day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    Log.e("Amountout", m.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    //  day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.album_title));
                    Log.e("Amountout", m.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            }


        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("workeradvance") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("kgroupadvance") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("otherexpense") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("vehicle")) {
            if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer")) {
                day_name.setText(m.getName());
                day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
                day_type.setText(m.getType());
                String locat = String.valueOf(databaseHandler.getfarmerlocation(m.getMobileno()));
                locat = locat.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
                Log.e("farmerlocation", locat);
                daybook_location.setText(locat);
                if (m.getName() != null && m.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (m.getDescription() != null && m.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }
                Log.e("amountout", m.getAmountout());
                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getAmountout());
                day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            } else {
                day_name.setText(m.getName());
                day_description.setText(m.getType());
                day_type.setText(m.getType());
                daybook_location.setText(m.getDescription());
                if (m.getName() != null && m.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (m.getDescription() != null && m.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }
                Log.e("amountout", m.getAmountout());
                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getAmountout());
                day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            }


        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("buyer")) {
            day_name.setText(m.getName());
            day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
            day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getAmountin());
            day_type.setText(" ");
            day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            daybook_location.setText(m.getType());
        }
        if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer")) {
            day_usertype.setText("F");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_farmer);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer")) {
            day_usertype.setText("FA");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_farmer);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("singleworker")) {
            day_usertype.setText("W");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("workeradvance")) {
            day_usertype.setText("WA");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("groupworker")) {
            day_usertype.setText("G");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("kgroupadvance")) {
            day_usertype.setText("GA");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("otherexpense")) {
            day_usertype.setText("E");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_otherexpense);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("vehicle")) {
            day_usertype.setText("V");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_vehicle);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("gsalary")) {
            day_usertype.setText("GS");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("isalary")) {
            day_usertype.setText("WS");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("payvehicle")) {
            day_usertype.setText("VP");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_vehicle);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("buyer")) {
            day_usertype.setText("B");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_buyer);
        }
    }


    return convertview;
}

public void isScrolling(boolean isScroll) {
    isListScrolling = isScroll;
    Log.e("Innerscrollcheck", String.valueOf(isListScrolling));
}

}
```

Exception:

> Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across
>   processes.)
>                                           java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
>                                               at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateAllPhoneStateLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:3321)
>                                               at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.notePhoneSignalStrengthLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:3351)
>                                               at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.notePhoneSignalStrength(BatteryStatsService.java:395)
>                                               at com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.broadcastSignalStrengthChanged(TelephonyRegistry.java:1448)
>                                               at com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.notifySignalStrengthForSubscriber(TelephonyRegistry.java:869)
>                                               at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephonyRegistry$Stub.onTransact(ITelephonyRegistry.java:184)
>                                               at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:451)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5` it clearly says that you are trying to access index 5 of an array whose length if 5.

Comment: @HardikModha where i have to male change in the coding can you tell me bcoz i am new to programming

Comment: Can you check this line: `final Daybooklist m = daybooklists.get(position);` What is the value of `position` you are getting?

**PS**: There is lots of code for anyone to go through, Always try to provide minimal code.

Comment: @HardikModha when i checked there it shows me the position as 5 and when i scroll the list it shows as 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: That's where the problem is. I hope You know that arrays starts from index 0. Right? So if you will try to access an array of length 5, you need to access as indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: @HardikModha so what i have to do to solve this issue

Comment: Just make sure that you are passing position from index 0 and so on.

Comment: @HardikModha can u show where i have to make change in the adapter class in detail